# json search using laravel query builder issues

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

```
["php", "css", "Mysql"]
["html", "css", "js"]
["js","css"]
```

This is value for 'keywords' field in 3 records

I need search result for this

```
["php","css"]
```

ie, result should contain the above 3 record as there is 'php' in 1st record and 'css' in other 2 records

`SELECT * FROM`job_posts`WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(keywords, '["php","css"]')`

only giving the 1st record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array:2 [
  0 => "php"
  1 => "css"
]
```

Made use of array instead of json_encoded format($request['keywords] itself)

```
 DB::table('job_posts')
    ->when($keywords, function ($query) use ( $keywords) {
        foreach ($keywords as $key => $value) {
            $query->orWhere('keywords', 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%');
        }
    }
    ->get();
```